# PHP: json_decode - reading category names

Tags: php, json, bitcoin, poloniex

I am trying to read JSON formatted prices from:
https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker

what I need are two things: symbol names (like BTC_BBR, BTC_BCN, etc) and "highestBid" price for them. To read the ladder I use something like this:

```
$polo_price = file_get_contents('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker');
$polo = json_decode($polo_price, true);
$symbol[1] =  $polo['BTC_BBR']['highestBid'];
```

But i need to use symbol name to read it. The symbols disapear and are being added from time to time, so I need to do this more automatically. How can I read symbol names into an array, so the result are:

```
symbol_name[0] = "BTC_BBR";
symbol_name[1] = "BTC_BCN";
```

and so on.

Comment: what is the issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$polo_price = file_get_contents('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker');
$polo = json_decode($polo_price, true);

foreach ($polo as $symbol=>$array){
    $symbols[]=$symbol;
    $highestBids[] = $array['highestBid'];
}

print_r($symbols);

print_r($highestBids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function findHighestBid()
{
    $result = [];
    $url = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker";
    $json_data = file_get_contents($url);
    $array_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
    foreach ($array_data as $currncy_option => $value) {
        $result[$currncy_option] = $value["highestBid"];
    }
    return $result;
}
print_r(findHighestBid());
```

It will automatically get the highest bid for all the currency option in the json data and also set currency as the key 
//output

```
Array
(
    [BTC_BBR] => 0.00026283
    [BTC_BCN] => 0.00000005
    [BTC_BELA] => 0.00002100
    [BTC_BITS] => 0.00000892
    [BTC_BLK] => 0.00003480
    [BTC_BTCD] => 0.00615298
```

Like this ....